# mPDF- how to apply auto break on row of the table

Tags: php, mpdf

I have used the HTML table structure and the mPDF library to generate PDF. but when I try to add long text, the first page displayed blank and all text displayed on the second page(due to the header of the first page. Please check images).
[image]
[image]

So How can I auto break the text into multiple pages?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51287846/5962802